# How do I use the HTML attribute in i18n's TValueConverter with parameters?

Tags: aurelia

In Aurelia's i18n it's possible to use HTML tags by this:

```
<span t="[html]title">Title</span>
```

But how do I use HTML tags when I need to use TValueConverter syntax like this one:

```
${'title' | t: {'some':'param'}}
```

I need to use that syntax because I have some parameters to pass here.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in the [docs](http://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/i18n#using-the-plugin) here.

```
// Translation file
{
  "paramstest": "Some text with <strong>{{content}}</strong>"
}
```

---

```
// View 
<span t="[html]paramstest" t-params.bind="params"></span>
```

---

```
// ViewModel
class MyVM {
  params = { content: 'ABC' }

  [...]
}
```